# How to create C++ class in android project via Eclipse?

Tags: android, c++

In order for reuse ability on iOS, I would like to write the logic for my Android game in C++ rather than java. How can I create a C++ class in eclipse and integrate it into my application?

I have read "native C++ code can be used on Android as well using the Native Development Kit (NDK)". What is the latest and greatest way to do this? I am writing a simple OpenGL app? Are there any tutorials out there that people have found useful?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate using the JNI and NDK here: 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I have written a multi platform 2D engine that runs on a fair amount of platforms. It's possible to do though not relatively easy to implement.

The way I did it was split it up in 2 parts where I used Java for the Activity lifecycle and some additional assist functionality and library encapsulated C++ code for all the rest.

For the C++ I used the JNI where I had two shared libraries. One library held the core logic that ran the entire game and then the other library was a sort of passthrough library with a couple of methods that were called from Java. This way, I could just recompile the core library on each platform without a lot of difficulties and I could rewrite the UI section for each platform. On iOS, I wrote it in Obj-C, on android in Java and on Windows in C/C++.